# Regex pattern to match date and size from string

Tags: regex

I have a string that contains a date and a file size.

> *Uploaded 11-20 2017, Size 11.93 GiB, ULed by P_O_O_P* (should match both)
>
> *Uploaded 11-20 15:20, Size 11.93 GiB, ULed by P_O_O_P* (should only match size since date year is missing)
>
> *Uploaded 11-20 2017, Size, ULed by P_O_O_P*  (should match date only, since size is not availabile)

and created the following regex for it

```
\b(\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{4})\b.*?\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*[TGMK]iB)
```

I would like to capture in group 0 the date `11-20 2017` and in group 1
the size `11.93 GiB/MiB/TiB/KiB`.

Sometimes the date is incomplete without a year. Then at least the size should match. Sometimes the size may not be available, then the date should match.

Therefore the regex should capture always either the string or the date or both (depending on what is available).

I tried it with the OR operator `|`, according to [regex100](https://regex101.com/r/JpYmLk/1) it works, but in my application (QRegularExpression supports OR) Group 0 and Group 1 are then the date only.

```
\b(\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{4})\b.*?|\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*[TGMK]iB)
```

> Group 0 "09-27 2017"
>
> Group 1 "09-27 2017"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "Sometimes only the date is available and sometimes only the size." -- can you please give a more complete example set of strings that you'd like to match? You've only given one example, which does not demonstrate either of your edge cases (which is crucial to your question).

Comment: @Tom Lord please see my updated example. thank you.

Comment: @user3606329 is `(..-.. .{4})|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s\w{3})`  what you need? https://regex101.com/r/JpYmLk/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [`(\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{4})|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s(?:GiB|MiB|TiB|KiB))`](https://regex101.com/r/RlTQ5s/2/)

This matches your input examples, if you have any other conditions I can adjust it.

```
(
  \d{2}                // two digis
  -                    // a dash
  \d{2}                // two digits
  \s                   // a whitespace character
  \d{4}                // four digits
)
|                      // Alternative
(
  \d+                  // one or more digits
  (
    ?:                 // non capture group
    \.                 // a . character
    \d+                // one or more digits
  )?                   // optional
  \s                   // whitespace character
  (
    ?:                 // non capture group
    GiB|MiB|TiB|KiB    // One of these
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works as expected. Is there a reason not to use `[GMTK]iB`?

Comment: @user3606329: Readability. It reduces to the same state machine.